# How can I make it so that a subclass of InputStream that reads Unicode chars over 255 reads those chars and creates a byte array without overflowing?

Tags: java, arrays, unicode, inputstream

I am learning Java in a website learning platform and they have this Unit Test framework where they substitute System.out and System.in with their own versions of input / output streams to check and inject data into the programs for testing. While doing some of this site exercises, there was an exercise that provided text in Czech and the first test case tested my output against a word with this character: `ř`

Well, I failed the test because my input replaced that `ř` with a `Y`.

Trying to understand why, I realized that `ř` has Unicode value `\u0159` and `Y` has Unicode value `\u0059`. In binary, representing both in two bytes they correspond to:

```
ř 0000 0001 0101 1001
Y 0000 0000 0101 1001
```

Can you spot the problem? I did spot it right away. The most significant byte was getting lost somewhere in the guts of that Testing framework.

After some digging I found this class that extends `InputStream`, which they use to replace System.in, and has the following `read()`

```java
    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (len == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        
        int c = read();
        if (c == -1) {
            return -1;
        }
        b[off] = (byte) c;

        int i = 1;
        try {
            for (; i < len; i++) {
                if (c == '\n') {
                    break;
                }
                c = read();
                if (c == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                b[off + i] = (byte) c;
            }
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Turns out that the line `int c = read();` gets the integer value of the next char of the input String.
Well, the char `ř` has decimal value `345` which is past 255, so the most significant byte gets lost and the above method fills the `byte[] b` buffer with chars that lost data.

After this long contextualization (sorry, I am trying to be as clear as I can) I ask:

What could be done to this sublcass of InputStream in order to properly convert all `c`'s in the inputted text into a byte array??

I tried this, but seems very cheesy to me, as this is not really reading whatever input comes byte by byte. I don't know. It just seems very cheaty and non-generic:

```java
    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (len == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int c = read();
        if (c == -1) {
            return -1;
        }
        b[off] = (byte) c;
        b[off + 1] = (byte) (c >> 8);

        int i = 2;
        try {
            for (; i < len; i++) {
                if (c == '\n') {
                    break;
                }
                c = read();
                if (c == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                b[off + i] = (byte) c;
                ++i;
                b[off + i] = (byte) (c >> 8);
            }
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
        return i;
    }
```

This works into returning a correct array representing all the bytes present in the input but, the resulting byte array doesn't get interpreted as a group of two bytes to the rest of the framework...

I have really exceeded my Java capabilities to pinpoint this issue, as I am just a beginner and I have exhausted all my tools to find a way around this.

[Here's my fork of said library.](https://github.com/msmilkshake/hs-test)

[Here's a direct link to the relevant class](https://github.com/msmilkshake/hs-test/blob/master/src/main/java/org/hyperskill/hstest/dynamic/input/SystemInMock.java)

Sorry for the long post.

Cheers!

Comment: Why are you trying to get a byte array? If you actually want to correctly read Unicode strings use `InputStreamReader`. Once you have a String, you can easily convert it to bytes using `String.getBytes(Charset)`...

Comment: I really don't know why... I was just trying to hot-fix this framework bug... I guess I can try making this class extend InputStreamReader instead.

Comment: @jurez InputStreamReader takes an InputStream as constructor parameter and it doesn't extend InputStream, so it's no good to replace the default System.in...

Comment: Why do you want to replace System.in? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I know it's boring to read, but the answer is within the first paragraph. This is not my framework.

Comment: The problem is not that it's boring but that it's not clear. I read your post three times and I still don't understand what's your point. Are you trying to fix a 3rd party testing library in order to make your tests pass?

Comment: "they (the website) have this Unit Test framework where they substitute System.out and System.in with their own versions of input / output streams to check and inject data into the programs for testing."

Comment: No use repeating what you already wrote. Please edit your post and add context who is doing what, with example of your code that is failing, and expected behaviour.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do here? `InputStream` is a stream of *bytes* (binary data) - it does not know about Unicode, or characters. If you're getting the wrong characters out from an InputStream, the problem is not with the stream, but with how you use it. After a brief look at the test framework you are cloning, it looks like there are serious errors with how characters and bytes are handled

Comment: You should be using a `Reader` constructed with the appropriate charset. No need to extend or override anything.